# Grammatical term for topicizing in English: Thing, question/statement about thing

Tags: word-order, topicizing

I'm looking for the name of a style of sentence construction.

"That word; I do not think it means what you think it means."

(I know that is not the correct quote. Moving on)

ASL has a common structure of topicizing: presenting the emphasized part of a sentence first, and then talking about it: "CAT, DOG CHASE" means "The dog chased the cat", or more accurately, "The cat, the dog chased it". This emphasizes the cat rather than the more straightforward "DOG CHASE CAT".

Is it just *anastrophe* or **do we have a more specific term**?

Comment: It's a quote from the [princess bride](http://www.strategicdc.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/inconceivable.jpg).

Comment: Neither the OED, nor Oxford Dictionaries generally, have heard of 'topicize', and neither, incidentally, has Wiktionary nor Wikipedia.

Comment: The verb is _topicalize_, in general, not "topicize". There are several different kinds of syntactic rules with that effect. One of them (C.1 [in this list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf)) is called "Topicalization".

Comment: @JohnLawler - is it not anastrophe?

Comment: If you say so. I don't care what the Greeks might have called it. The Greeks didn't know much English syntax, after all.

Comment: if you want to emphasize the cat, why not "The Cat was chased by the dog"

Comment: That's another way; there are a lot of grammatical ways to do that. [Check the list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf). Emphasizing is a matter of speaker's intent, not grammar.

Comment: I'm looking for the name of this type of sentence construction

Comment: *"The cat, the dog chased it".* -- left dislocation construction. You might be interested in the topic of *information packaging*.

Comment: @WS2 I'm guessing the intended term is topicalization. But that's not exactly what they have in mind, I suppose. 

From an SFL perspective, I suppose we'd analyse it (at least in Periodicity) as a marked theme, but again, I don't think it's the answer they're looking for.

Comment: Wait, did he just invent three new question tags? :)  If other languages really are relevant, I should mention that this is an extremely common sentence structure in Japanese.  Maybe you could ask a Japanese Language expert.

Comment: topicize is what American Sign Language calls their left dislocation construction (that you @F.E.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *synonym* for **anastrophe** is [hyperbaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton), but anastrophe is referred to as a more specific instance of hyperbaton in that the changing of the position of only a single word changes its emphasis.

In this case, **anastrophe** is the most specific term and the best one.

There are other terms used to describe unusual order (or disorder) of words. These are:

- [Hysteron proteron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteron_proteron)
- [Hypallage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage)
- [Hysterologia](http://www.odlt.org/ballast/hysterologia.html)
- [Parenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29)
- [Epergesis](http://dailytrope.com/2007/12/11/epergesis/)
- [Tmesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis)
- [Synchysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchysis)